# Need Regex allowing only 4 digits and one alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Max Length of string is 5 (including one alphabet). If there is no alphabet, allowed length of digits is 4.

Digits allowed: `0` to `9999`

One alphabet is allowed(Only if string has at least one number). Some examples:

- Allowed: `1a`, `a2`, `1111a`, `1a22`, `9999`
- Not allowed: `99999`, `11111`,`a`,`aa`

I tried:

```
       ^(?:[0-9]|[a-z](?=[^a-z]*$)){1,5}$
```

This works for cases: `1a`, `a2`, `1111a`, `1a22`, `9999`. But it incorrectly allows `99999` as well.
Any help on how to restrict the digit length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:(?=\d*[a-z]\d*$)(?=.*[0-9])(?:[a-z0-9]){1,5}|[0-9]{1,4})$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/10

Comment: More than one alphabet and only alphabet isn't allowed. Only numbers are allowed or including an alphabet as well is allowed. **Allowed: 12,123a, a1** | **Not Allowed:a,aa,12345**

Comment: This is allowing 8aa,a8aa. More than one alphabet isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Regexes aren't good at keeping counts of things, as you've discovered.  In this case, a lookahead will put you right:

```
^\d{1,4}$|^(?=\d*[a-z]\d*$)[a-z\d]{1,5}$
```

We start by using `^\d{1,4}$` to get the simplest case out of the way first.  If that fails, the second alternative, the second alternative takes over.  The first thing it does is use `(?=\d*[a-z]\d*$)` to assert that there is exactly one letter in the string.  If the lookahead succeeds, the match position returns to the beginning of the string, allowing us match the whole string again, this time with `[a-z\d]{1,5}$`.

It isn't really necessary to verify that the rest of the characters are digits at this point.  I could have used `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z][a-z]*$` instead.  We just need to make sure it looks at the whole string.  I just think it's more self-documenting with `\d*`.

Note that this regex will match a string consisting of just a letter.  If you want to make sure there's at least one digit as well, change the final `{1,5}` to `{2,5}`.

Here's the **[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/8)**.

Comment: Thank you Alan. Explained beautifully. I was confused with the usage of **?:** and **?=**

Answer (score 0):

Use `{size}` for restrict the length of String in regex.

I update the regex:

```
^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?:[0-9]|[a-z]){1,5}|[0-9]{4})$
```

Comment: What's up with `(?:[0-9]|[a-z])`? Why not `[0-9a-z]`?

Comment: @codeaholicguy More than one alphabet and only alphabet isn't  allowed. Only numbers are allowed or including an alphabet as well is allowed. **Allowed: 12,123a, a1,9999** | **Not Allowed:a,aa,12345**